# How to fix issue with nutch readseg not dumping any content?

Tags: nutch, dump

I am using Nutch 1.4 local on iOS, to crawl a website and nutch 
    readseg dump does not return any relevant information. 
    What am I missing?
    I am trying to extract 'category' as new metadata from url. 
    I am using replace to extract substring from the url. I am able to 
    run the code and index the documents in Google Cloud Search. But 
    it is not capturing the category.
    To debug this end to end I like to verify that the correct value 
    is extracted by nutch in category metadata. I verified that regex 
    is correct with a regex tester. I want to log metadata
    values - url, category in the log or stdout. I so not see any 
    pertinent information in hadoop.log even in DEBUG.

```
$bin/nutch readseg -dump TestCrawl/segments/* segmentAllContent  
SegmentReader: dump segment: TestCrawl/segments/20190128171825 
SegmentReader: done 

logs/hadoop.log -  
2019-01-29 11:40:02,275 INFO  segment.SegmentReader - 
SegmentReader: 
dump segment: TestCrawl/segments/20190128171825 . 
2019-01-29 11:40:02,463 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to 
load  
native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java 
classes where applicable.  

log4j.properties    

    log4j.logger.org.apache.nutch=DEBUG

nutch-site.xml   

<property>  
    <name>index.replace.regexp</name>  
    <value>  
        urlmatch=.*mycompany\.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)  
        url:category=$1 
    </value>  
</property>    
<property>
    <name>urlmeta.tags</name>
    <value>title,category</value>
    <description>
     test
    </description>
</property>
<property>
   <name>index.parse.md</name>  
 <value>*</value>
 <description> test </description
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `readseg -dump` command only writes everything contained in the segment as plain text to the output directory `segmentAllContent`. It does not run the indexer and consequently does not call the plugin index-replace. You may use the command `bin/nutch indexchecker` to check whether the plugin is configured properly.

Please note that the plugin index-replace is not available in Nutch 1.4, it has been added with Nutch 1.11.

Example how to use the indexchecker to check the index-replace plugin:

```
% bin/nutch indexchecker \
   -Dplugin.includes='protocol-okhttp|parse-html|index-(basic|replace|static)' \
   -Dindexingfilter.order='org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter org.apache.nutch.indexer.staticfield.StaticFieldIndexer org.apache.nutch.indexer.replace.ReplaceIndexer' \
   -Dindex.static='category:unknown' \
   -Dindex.replace.regexp=$'hostmatch=localhost\ncategory=/.+/intranet/' \
   http://localhost/
...
host :  localhost
id :    http://localhost/
title : Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page: It works
category :      intranet
url :   http://localhost/
...
```

- the plugin index-static is configured to add a field "category" with value "unknown"
- the plugin index-replace changes the value to "intranet" if the hostname is "localhost" (the `$'...'` notation is expands `\n`)

Comment: my bad - the nutch version is 1.14 that I am running.  The indexer is ok since i am seeing data on the data source on the other end.  Whats the best way to dump the data before it is forwarded to the data source?

Comment: Use the `bin/nutch indexchecker`, like Sebastian suggested.

Comment: Thanks Jorge!  I got the metadata list & have url : https://www.perficient.com/industries/automotive  but i do not see the category? Why is it not extracted?

Comment: indexchecker doesn't show category in the metadata.  What else can I check? I have parse-metatags and index-metadata in plougin as well as nutch-site.xml

Comment: If it is not shown it hasn't been added. Which plugin adds the field "category"?

Comment: I've added an example how test index-replace using the indexchecker. If the  "category" is passed via urlmeta.tags it must be injected as a metadata field, see the description of `urlmeta.tags`.

Comment: bin/nutch indexchecker -Dindex.replace.regexp='urlmatch=https:\/\/www.perficient.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\ncategory=$1' https://www.perficient.com/industries


category : unknown
url : https://www.perficient.com/industries

I checked for plugins you mentioned in your command and its all there in nutch-site.xml .  Also I checked the regex with https://regex101.com/ and category is in group1 .  Looks like I may just be missing syntax

Comment: <property>
    <name>index.replace.regexp</name>
    <value>
       url:category=;https://www.perficient.com/([a-zA-Z]+)/(.*);$1;     
    </value>
</property>      I had to change ; as separator and it worked. Thanks for your help Sebastian